# Cannot load data from Volley to Fragment (Tab Layout)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley, android-tablayout

I am trying to load data from mysql database to Fragment In Tab layout using volley. The problem is that the function is getting the data from DB but it is not loading into the fragment.

When I tried to add hard coded data inside the list it works and data is loaded into the fragment. But it wont work with volley. Please Help

Here is my Fragment Code:

```
public class DriverFragment extends Fragment {
    View v;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    Context ctx;
    private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://192.168.10.11/AutoBus/show_driver.php";
    List<DriverModel> mData;
    public DriverFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.driver_frgment, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.mon_data);
        DriverAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new DriverAdapter(getContext(),mData);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mData = new ArrayList<>();

        /*mData.add(new DriverModel("Asad","092 4587455","Asss","ssss","dddddd"));
        mData.add(new DriverModel("Asad","092 4587455","Asss","ssss","dddddd"));
        mData.add(new DriverModel("Asad","092 4587455","Asss","ssss","dddddd"));
        mData.add(new DriverModel("Asad","092 4587455","Asss","ssss","dddddd"));
*/

        loadDetails();
    }

    private void loadDetails() {


        /*
         * Creating a String Request
         * The request type is GET defined by first parameter
         * The URL is defined in the second parameter
         * Then we have a Response Listener and a Error Listener
         * In response listener we will get the JSON response as a String
         * */
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject data = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                //adding the product to product list
                                mData.add(new DriverModel(
                                        data.getString("bus_number"),
                                        data.getString("driver_uname"),
                                        data.getString("driver_password"),
                                        data.getString("driver_id"),
                                        data.getString("driver_phone")
                                ));
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                });

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After set data on list call notifyDataSetChanged() method of adapter class inside onResponse(String response) method of volley request

```
  // make global object DriverAdapter class
    DriverAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;


     for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        //getting product object from json array
        JSONObject data = array.getJSONObject(i);
        //adding the product to product list
        mData.add(new DriverModel(data.getString("bus_number"),
        data.getString("driver_uname"),
        data.getString("driver_password"),
        data.getString("driver_id"),
        data.getString("driver_phone")));
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

  //after set data on list,call here notifiyDataSetChanged() method
  recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Sir I have tried this but now I am getting Null Object Error. Please help, I will be very thankful

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.sbtcc.zimcon;



import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.sbtcc.zimcon.ui.main.Product;
import com.sbtcc.zimcon.ui.main.VendorcustomListAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class VendorsFragment extends Fragment {

    private View VendorsProView;
    private String URL_GET_USERPRODUCT = "http://192.168.1.6/ZimCon/IndividualSell/GetAllProducts.php";

    private View PrivateUserProductsView;
    private ArrayList<Product> arrayList;
    private ListView lv;
    private String URL_GET_USERPRODUCTS = "http://192.168.1.6/ZimCon/IndividualSell/GetMyProducts.php";
    private SessionManager sessionManager;
    private String UseId = "2";
    Context context;
    public VendorsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        VendorsProView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vendors, container, false);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = VendorsProView.findViewById(R.id.Listview);

        return VendorsProView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        GetProductFromServer();
    }
    private void GetProductFromServer() {

        final String UserId = UseId;


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_GET_USERPRODUCT,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String responseMyProductsPHP) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseMyProductsPHP);
                            String Success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("products");

                            if (Success.equals("1")){

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String id = object.getString("Product_Id");
                                    String image = object.getString("Product_img_link");
                                    String name = object.getString("Name");
                                    String prize = object.getString("Prize");
                                    String qty = object.getString("Qty");
                                    String sold = object.getString("Sold");

                                    String strName = name;
                                    String strPrice = prize;
                                    String strQty = qty;
                                    String vendorId = "9";

                                    arrayList.add(new Product(id, strName, image, strPrice, strQty, vendorId));
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error Json: "+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        VendorcustomListAdapter userCustomProductListAdapter = new VendorcustomListAdapter(
                                getContext(), R.layout.vendor_custom_product_listview, arrayList
                        );
                        lv.setAdapter(userCustomProductListAdapter);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error resp : "+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id", UserId);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi B.samu, welcome! Please consider adding more information.

Comment: Try to add information on why and how this is a solution so OP can learn from it.

Comment: sorry for late reply....okay thank you guy let me add and explain